# auto printing text files from folder in Cyrillic

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

i have web  application, which writes my labels in text file.Now that text file I send to printer directly with this: http://autoprint-pro.win7dwnld.com/ but font in text file is in Cyrillic, and this one is not print in cyrilic.Could you help me to find some like this to print my strings in text file in Cyrillic???

Comment: What encoding is used by those "text files"? Can you convert them to UTF-8 (if needed) before sending to the printer?

Comment: yes, i use utf-8,but nothing

Comment: solved,sorry, i've haven't putted utf-8 on right place